# Jquery , adding class to element

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a calender application using jquery.
I'm using a table that has a col for each date.

```
<td>17</td>
```

I want to add a class to the date that is today. Not very good with jquery though. How can I fix this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('td').load( function(){
          var today = new Date();
          if($(this).innerText()==  today.getDay(){
              this.addClass("today")
          }
      })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Are these just random guesses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need the `.load()`. `$(document).ready()` should do what you need.
You'll need to parse the date, too. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").each(function(){
        if($(this).text().trim() == new Date().getDate()){
            $(this).addClass("today");
        }
    });
});
```

Edited after I saw the data that is actually in the `<td>`s in the OP's post.

Comment: @jfriend00 I had this wrong initially, should be good now. I was assuming you had a whole date in the <td> instead of just the day of the month.

Comment: it only has the day of the month i.e. 18, for today.

Answer (score 1):

To add a class, you have to use a jQuery object like this as `addClass()` is a jQuery method, not a DOM method:

```
$(this).addClass("today");
```

Also, it seems likely that this line of code isn't doing what you want it to:

```
if($(this).innerText()==  today.getDay()
```

First, it's missing a closing paren at the end of the line.  Second, `getDay()` returns an integer 0 through 6 for the day of the week.  Is that really what you're trying to compare to the `innerText()`?